# Sentinel API error on Python: HTTP status 200 OK: API response not valid. JSON decoding failed

Tags: python, sentinel2, sentinelsat

I have been trying to follow an easy tutorial on how to get sentinel 2 images for a series of polygons I have. For some reason, no matter what I do I keep running into the same error (detailed above).

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.mask import mask
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import date
import sentinelhub

user = 'xxxxx'
password = 'xxxxx'
url = 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus'
api = SentinelAPI(user, password, url)

validation = gpd.read_file('EarthData/tutakoke_permafrost_validation/Tutakoke_permafrost_validation.shp')
plateau_transects = gpd.read_file('EarthData/tutakoke_permafrost_plateau_transects/Tutakoke_Permafrost_Plateau_Transects.shp')


validation = validation.set_crs(epsg=32604, inplace=True, allow_override=True)
validation['imdate']='01-01-2019'
validation['imdate'] = pd.to_datetime(validation2['imdate'])

validation['geometry2'] = validation.geometry.buffer(2, cap_style=3)

footprint=validation['geometry2'][1]

products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = ('20200109', '20200510'),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     processinglevel = 'Level-2A',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0, 20))
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 200 OK: API response not valid. JSON decoding failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah - it was that my footprint was not in the correct lat lon format!